# Calling a static method on a class

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, static

Given a method like the one below, that returns a Class...

```
-(Class)getClass
{
    return [MyAwesomeClass class];
}
```

...how do I call a static method on that class? I tried this, but it didn't work...

```
Class theClass = [anInstance getClass];
[theClass someStaticMethod];
```

How should I call a static method on `theClass`?

Edit to add:
It seems I was doing the right thing, and something else was causing the crash. Now I need to figure out how to get rid of the warning that the method `someStaticMethod` isn't found. What should I cast `theClass` to?

Comment: Static method or class method?

Comment: For my current use, a static method, but either would be useful

Comment: Do you mean a `+ classMethod`?

Comment: @Richard and @Radek, sorry for the confusion, by static method I actually mean +class method. Not an -instance method.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it didn't work"? Can you show the declaration and definition of 'someStaticMethod'?

Answer (score 4):

You do it exactly the way you've written it, assuming the class in question responds to `someStaticMethod`.

If it isn't working correctly, then one of these is most likely the case:

- You don't have the class you think
- The class doesn't respond to the message
- You declared the method incorrectly
- You haven't imported the header where the method is declared
- The method itself is buggy

Answer (score 4):

It is an old question but i answer it for completeness. if you use id instead of Class it will work

```
id theClass = [anInstance getClass];
[theClass someStaticMethod];
```

Compiler will be happy with this dynamic typing but you must be sure that Class will respond to +someStaticMethod or it will crash at runtime